# Listview won't update from realm

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, realm

After I create or receive a message send the message then save it to realm. Afterwards I need to update my threads ListView on the threads page and bring the newest messages to the top. I already have it so the thread list shows the updated preview and updated date, but it stays in it's inital ListView position. I tried to requery realm to get all info and reorder by the lastUpdated time, but it doesn't seem to work. Do I need to wipe the old thread list then repopulate it to get it to update?

I have the update triggered on the onResume()

```
    @Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    updateListview = true;
    updateList();
}
```

Here's my update

```
    @UiThread
public void updateList() {
    try {

        if (updateListview) {
            thread_realm = Realm.getInstance(this);
            results = thread_realm.where(ZipListModel.class).findAllSorted("zipupdated", RealmResults.SORT_ORDER_DESCENDING);
            adapter = new ZipListAdapter(this, results);
            threadsListView.setAdapter(adapter);

            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            if (results.size()==0){
                createZipHint.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            } else {
                createZipHint.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Adapter

```
package com.admin.zipline.adapters;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.support.v7.widget.CardView;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.admin.zipline.R;
import com.admin.zipline.activities.ZipListPage;
import com.admin.zipline.model.ZipListModel;

import org.androidannotations.annotations.ViewById;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;


public class ZipListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<ZipListModel>


  {
    List<ZipListModel> items;
 Context context;
 Typeface semiBold;
 Typeface light;
 Typeface regular;
 String[] months={};
 public ZipListModel ziplist;
 ArrayList<String> ziplistNames,ziplistParticipantsaids;
 public ZipListAdapter(Context context, List<ZipListModel> threadslist) {
     super(context,R.layout.zip_adapter_view,threadslist);
    this.context = context;
    this.items=threadslist;
}
@Override
public View getView(final int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder holder ;
    if (view == null) {
        holder =new ViewHolder();
        LayoutInflater inflater=(LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.zip_adapter_view, parent, false);
        light = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "ProximaNova-Light.otf");
        regular = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "ProximaNova-Regular.otf");
        semiBold = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(),"ProximaNova-Semibold.otf");
        //TODO
        /*for showing the author image
        * */
        //holder.thread_image = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.author_avatar);
        holder.thread_text = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.threadtext);
        holder.thread_name = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.threadname);
        holder.last_updated = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.lastupdated);
        holder.zip_members=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.ziplist_members);
        holder.thread_text.setTypeface(light);
        holder.thread_name.setTypeface(semiBold);
        holder.zip_members.setTypeface(regular);
        view.setTag(holder);
    }else{
        holder =(ViewHolder)view.getTag();
    }
    try{
        ziplist = items.get(position);
        ziplistNames = new ArrayList<String>();
        ziplistParticipantsaids=new ArrayList<>();

    if (ziplist != null) {
       if (ziplist.getMessagesListsmodel().first().getText()!=null){
           holder.thread_text.setText(ziplist.getMessagesListsmodel().first().getText());
       }
       if (ziplist.getMessagesListsmodel().first().getCreatedAt()!=null){
            holder.last_updated.setText(getDate(ziplist.getMessagesListsmodel().first().getCreatedAt()));
        }


        for (int i = 0; i < ziplist.getParticipantsmodel().size(); i++) {
            ziplistNames.add(ziplist.getParticipantsmodel().get(i).getName());
            ziplistParticipantsaids.add(ziplist.getParticipantsmodel().get(i).getParticipantId());
        }

        String members="";
        for (int i=0;i<ziplistNames.size();i++){
            members+=ziplist.getParticipantsmodel().get(i).getFirstName()+", ";
        }
       if (members.length() > 3){
           members=members.substring(0,members.length()-2);
       }

        holder.zip_members.setText(members);


        if(ziplist.getZipname().isEmpty()){
            holder.thread_name.setText(members);
        } else {
            holder.thread_name.setText(ziplist.getZipname());
        }
    }
    }
    catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
 view.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(ziplist.getZipColor()));

    return view;
}
String getDate(Date date) {
           try {
                Date d = date;
               months=context.getResources().getStringArray(R.array.months);
               return months[d.getMonth()] + " " + (d.getDate());
           } catch (Exception e) {
               e.printStackTrace();
               return "";
    }
}
public class ViewHolder{
    ImageView thread_image;
    TextView thread_text,thread_name,last_updated,zip_members;
   // CardView cardView;
}
```

}

Comment: @MarkusRubey The thread that had the new message should move to the top of the ListView, but it stays in it's original spot when the thread was created. So if the thread has 2 other threads (Items) above it, and the thread gets updated, I need it to be at the top (0 position) of the ListView. It's for a messagnig app.

Answer (score 1):

The question is not quite clear to me but i can suggest some common ways to do this.

Assume your ZipListModel defined like this:

```
public class ZipListModel extends RealmObject {
    private String title;
    private Date date;
    private String Author;

    ... getters and setters...
}
```

The easiest way to show your models in the ListView is using RealmBaseAdapter. You can find document [here](https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#adapter). And [example](https://github.com/realm/realm-java/tree/master/examples/adapterExample).

eg.:

```
public class ZipListAdapter extends RealmBaseAdapter<ZipListModel> implements ListAdapter {
    public ZipListAdapter(Context context, int resId,
                     RealmResults<ZipListModel> realmResults,
                     boolean automaticUpdate) {
        super(context, realmResults, automaticUpdate);
    }

    ...

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
       // Update your views with the realmResults
       ...
       ZipListModel zlm = realmResults.get(position);
       authorTextView.setText(zlm.getAuthor);
       ...
    }
    ...
}
```

The benifit of using RealmBaseAdapter is the realmResults can be updated automatically when the Realm transaction commited which means in your case, whenever you update your Realm by

```
thread_realm = Realm.getInstance(this);
thread_realm.beginTransaction()
// Change something in your Realm
... 
thread_realm.commitTransaction()
```

The ZipListAdapter's notifyDataSetChanged will be called automatically and the listView will be updated.

BTW, you can still stay with your own adpater and simply update it by using RealmChangeListener. See [example](https://github.com/realm/realm-java/blob/7c21c33095559fe828f2cccecaf57aef59bc1a8a/examples/threadExample/src/main/java/io/realm/examples/threads/ThreadFragment.java) .

Answer (score 0):

Try use `RealmBaseAdapter.UpdateData(RealmResult<T> result)`. My project has similar requirement and it works for me

https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/api/io/realm/RealmBaseAdapter.html